# How to remove .php extension and add a trailing slash in specific folder with .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I currently have a URL that looks like this:

```
www.mysite.com/folder-name/page-name.php
```

but I need it to look like this:

```
www.mysite.com/folder-name/page-name/
```

I'm after a regular expression for the .htaccess that goes in "folder-name" and targets only the folder it is in.   It needs to remove the .php extension and redirect to a url with a trailing slash at the end.

Also if the url is `www.mysite.com/folder-name/` I need the the expression to be ignored to avoid a // at the end. I've had a look but couldn't find a solution for just a particular folder. Just beginning with PHP and regex's are blowing my mind!.

I've found code like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+.php
RewriteRule (.*).php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

but it returns urls unto this:

```
www.mysite.com/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/folder_name/page_name/
```

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

I can remove the .php with this. Just not sure how to add the slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the path like that is because apache is guessing whether your rule's target (`$0/`) is a file path or URL path, and it's guessing incorrectly that it's a file path. You need to either provide a rewrite base:

```
RewriteBase /
```

or make your targets absolute URI's

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Brilliant, is there a way to RewriteBase not as the root at / but one level down in a folder thats not absolute?

Comment: @user2136584 Not sure what you mean, the baes is essentially what comes after your hostname in `http://hostname.com`, so `/` means `http://hostname.com/` and /foo/` means `http://hostname.com/foo/`